# Using Non-English characters for function/variable names in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

I want to use Hindi language characters in VC++ on VS2010. Is it possible, and if yes then how can I do it?

I think it will involve playing around with locales, language packs etc., which I don't know much about?

PC configuration:

VS 2010 on Windows 7 English(India)

Comment: [Microsoft says you can do it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx)

Comment: I don't care if you love Hindi, but you'll go to **programmer hell** if you do this - and a fair warning - *it's a very, very bad place*. -1

Comment: Why concentrating on what divides instead of on what unites?

Comment: Writing code in any other language but US English isn't all that good an idea. Imagine writing *colour* instead of *colour*. Now imagine writing "रंग" instead. Baaaaad idea.

Comment: I'm not gonna do it,just wanted to know out of curosity....:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the C++ source is required to understand Unicode (ISO 10646). For example 2.11 [lex.name] paragraph 1 reads:

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits. Each universal-character-name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding in ISO 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in E.1. The initial element shall not be a universal-character-name designating a character whose encoding falls into one of the ranges specified in E.2. Upper- and lower-case letters are different. All characters are significant.

Whether it is an award-winning idea to create source code which can't be read by most programmers is a different idea. In general, security by obfuscation doesn't work: even if all your identifiers are essentially unreadable by many people, the structure of the program can still be decoded. However, I can promise you that I won't give any help with programs posted e.g. over here which I can't read: I'm already put off to some extend by identifiers using the ASCII subset of Unicode but a language I don't understand. If the characters don't make any sense to me either, I have probably no inclination to spend any time on the source. Sure, in the long distant past I had created a version of gcc which used German keywords. It didn't work too well because it already didn't understand the standard headers so I dropped it even before having written the obligatory "hello, world"-program.